# Pegar valordinâmico de id - JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Estou usando PHP com AJAX. Preciso pegar um id de vários forms e executar uma função no AJAX.
Estou passando as ids dos forms assim :

```
<form id="formItem<?= $idItem ?>">
```

Porém, no JQuery não consigo obter a id, cada form tem uma id diferente. Todos na mesma página.
Meu AJAX:

```
$('#formItem').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var idProduto = $('#idProduto').val();
    var precoProduto = $('#precoProduto').val();
    var qtdeCompra = $('#qtdeCompra').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/fcgeti_bairrojuventude/loja2/inserir.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {idProd: idProduto, precoProd: precoProduto, qtdeProd: qtdeCompra},
        dataType: 'json'
    });
    getItens();       

});
```

Se puderem me ajudar. Já tentei concatenar mas não deu certo.

Obrigado

Comment: qnd eu não consigo pegar id de algum elemento eu tento fazer isso antes de submeter a requisição ajax, pra debugar e verificar algum erro com o console do navegador aberto pra exibir qualquer erro e já dentro do codigo javascript coloco: `alert( $('#id_que_eu_quer0').val()+'/ '+ $('#id_seguinte').val());´     // caso haja algum erro vc verá no console se algum elemento está retornando undefined ou outro valor....

Answer (score 0):

O problema aí está relacionado à manipulação do DOM; lembre-se que o **Id** de um elemento nunca pode repetir; então nessa situação você pode trabalhar com as classes para identificar os elementos. Fiz um exemplo abaixo sem precisar misturar o PHP dentro do script, espero que ajude:

```js
$('.form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    //pega o id do formulário
    var formId = $(this).attr('id');
    
    //pega todos os seus valores (e nomes dos campos) POST de uma vez
    var str = $(this).serialize();
    
    $('#consoleLog').html('formulário:'+formId+'<br />Data:'+str);
    
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form" id="1">
  <input type="text" name="i1" value="v1" />
  <button type="submit">Enviar form 1</button>
 </form>
 <br />
 <form class="form" id="2">
 <input type="text" name="i2" value="v2" />
  <button type="submit">Enviar form 2</button>
 </form>
 <br />
 <form class="form" id="3">
  <input type="text" name="i3" value="v3" />
  <button type="submit">Enviar form 3</button>
 </form>
 
 <p id="consoleLog"></p>
```